# How to know database file path after publishing project in visual studio?

Tags: c#-4.0

I published my project in visual studio by right-click on my project and click publish, the problem is the database file path is changed and i can't find it, i need the path to put it in connection string
can any one help me, please.

Comment: Where did you originally store the connection string? A Settings file? Can't you change the project and publish again?

Comment: i put my connection string in app.config file

Comment: Change it in the project and republish it.

Comment: ok, but what is the new path? where visual studio publish the database files?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will publish an application to a folder where you've told it to; by default it's `[project directory]\publish\`. The files for a particular publish will be in `[publish directory]\Application Files\[revision number]\` by default.

You can check the path by right-clicking on a project in the solution in Visual Studio, selecting Properties and then the Publish tab. If the path is relative, it's in the project directory.

In the Application Files folder, you will find a bunch of files with `.deploy` extensions; if you've put your configuration in `app.config`, you should be able to edit it by opening the file `[Project name].exe.config.deploy` in a text editor.

It's an XML file and you should be able to identify the part you need to change. It will typically look like

```
 <setting name="SettingName" serializeAs="String">
    <value>some setting value</value>
 </setting>
```

Installing the application with the created setup file, assuming that the hand-changed revision is the newest one in the `Application Files` folder, *should* install it with the new connection string.

I *still* urge you to consider just changing the `app.config` file within the project and doing a publish again, this is the way you *should* be doing it.